# I can't send an email with Curl

Tags: libcurl

My goal is to send an email with gmail through a Curl C program. Whenever I run this, I get an SSL error even if I specified the option to use SSL

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t payload_source(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);

typedef struct {
  size_t bytes_read;
} upload_status;

char *from_addr = "<sender@gmail.com>";
char *to_addr = "<receiver@gmail.com>";

static const char *payload_text =
  "To: " "<receiver@gmail.com>" "\r\n"
  "From: " "<sender@gmail.com>" "\r\n"
  "Cc: " "" "\r\n"
  //"Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
  //"rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n"
  "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n"
  "\r\n" /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC 5322 */
  "This message is a test\r\n"
  "\r\n"
  "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n"
  "Check RFC 5322.\r\n";

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
    upload_status upload = { 0 };
    printf("This is a curl program\n");
    
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(!curl)
    {
        printf("Curl wasn't initialized!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Curl was initialized!\n");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, from_addr);

    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, to_addr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, from_addr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "password");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_ANY);

    printf("Sending email...\n");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)res, (int)CURLE_OK);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return (int)res;
}

static size_t payload_source(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    upload_status *upload_ctx = (upload_status *)userp;
    const char *data;
    size_t room = size * nmemb;

    if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
    }

    data = &payload_text[upload_ctx->bytes_read];

    if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    if(room < len)
        len = room;
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->bytes_read += len;

    return len;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My run.bat script looks like:

```
@echo off
del main.exe
cls
gcc -I src/include -L src/lib -o main *.c -lcurl -lssl -lssh2 -lbrotlicommon -lbrotlidec -lcrypto -lnghttp2 -lnghttp3 -lngtcp2_crypto_quictls -lngtcp2 -lz -lzstd
main
```

The error message I get from this code is: "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

If I add the path to cacert.pem to CURLOPT_SSLCERT, I get: "Problem with the local SSL certificate" and "unable to set private key file: 'cacert.pem' type PEM"

If I add the path to curl-ca-bundle.crt, I get: "Problem with the local SSL certificate" and "unable to set private key file: 'cert.crt' type PEM"

Comment: [`CURLOPT_SSLCERT` is for a CLIENT cert](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html) which needs to also have a privatekey hence the error you get. For _CA_ cert(s) used to validate the SERVER, see `CURLOPT_CAINFO CURLOPT_CAPATH` and related. That said, gmail (and google in general) uses a long-established CA root (GlobalSign) that should already be in the truststores of most platforms. What kind of system are you running on and what SSL/TLS implementation does your libcurl use and how (or by whom) was it built?

Comment: I use windows 11 and I downloaded the Curl library from their website, more specifically version 8.3.0

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it, thanks to dave_thompson_085.
The solution was to set CURLOPT_CAINFO to the path of the "curl-ca-bundle.crt" file which was in the bin folder of the curl download.
I renamed it to "cert.crt" so I added the line:

> curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cert.crt");

And everything worked flawlessly, thanks!